# open cv detect tables and chairs

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to detect tables and chairs from an image and do no have much success with the code below. It also detects other squares etc. Any hints?

[image]

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("nao.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
cv2.waitKey(0)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 250)
cv2.waitKey(0)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(edged, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.waitKey(0)

(_,cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
total = 0

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.01 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
         print approx
         cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 4)
         total += 1

print "I found {0} lines in that image".format(total)
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Could you post an example picture?

Comment: very hard task in general. http://xkcd.com/1425/

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Kitchen_table.jpg